# php array is null after appending elts

Tags: php, arrays

Im having problems with appending items to array. 
First I init the empty array and then I want to put elemnts inside.

But, result on the end is empty array.

```
$aditivs = array();

function handle_Aditiv($ArrVal){
  $id_aditiv = $ArrVal['id'];
  $code = $ArrVal['code'];
  $arrLocal = array();
  $arrLocal[] = $id_aditiv;
  $arrLocal[] = $code;
  $aditivs [] = $arrLocal;
 //var_dump($aditivs);
 echo "Adt : $id_aditiv,$code \r\n";
}

var_dump($aditivs); //this print out empty array
```

insted of:

```
$aditivs [] = $arrLocal;
```

I use also this, but the result is the same

```
array_push($aditivs, $arrLocal);
```

So where and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read about **variables' scope** in PHP. Your code would indeed work if it was javascript, but this is not... Besides, you are not even calling your function anywhere! Is it being executed at all?

Comment: $aditivs is global, so you can't change it

Comment: @Lukas No `$aditivs` isn't global

Comment: the function it is called.

Comment: this function is called many times and I want to  append elements on the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.php:

```
<?php 
$aditivs = array();


function handle_Aditiv($ArrVal){
    Global $aditivs;
    $aditivs[] = array($ArrVal['id'], $ArrVal['code']);
    return(0);
}

$arr = array('id'=>1, 'code'=>"code");
handle_Aditiv($arr);
var_dump($aditivs); 

 ?>
```

run:

```
>php test.php
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    string(4) "code"
  }
}
```

**BUT:**

Technically, the best way is using [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
<?php 
$aditivs = array();


function handle_Aditiv(&$accumulator, $input){
    $accumulator[] = array($input['id'], $input['code']);
}

$arr = array('id'=>1, 'code'=>"code");
handle_Aditiv($aditivs, $arr);

var_dump($aditivs); 

?>
```

For your case there is no difference, but in long, complex code it's makes the idea much clear.